# Megane 2002 auto started shaking and lost power

Tags: automatic-transmission, power, shaking, megane

This evening the car was driving fine and then suddenly when it was idle it started really shaking. We began to drive and it still shook but the engine light began to flash and you could feel the car losing power. We just about managed to get it home although we had to pause for a cyclist and the car momentarily cut out until my partner revved the engine and we got it to where it needed to be. There was a strong smell around the exhaust/back of the car.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question? Have you had the codes read? What is the strong smell?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.